# MS Access grouping query spanning start and end dates

Tags: sql, ms-access

I would like to get a running tally of how many widgets were/are rented at any one time, by month, by year. Data is held in an MS Access 2003 db;

- Table name: rent_table
- Fields:

  - rentid
  - startdate
  - enddate
  - rentfee
  - rentcost
  - bookingfee

Something like;  Count number of rentid's that fall between month/year, then group them?

e.g. if a widget was rented from 5th Jan 2014 to 8th April 2014 it would appear as a count in Jan, Feb, Mar and April tally's.

Many thanks.

### EDIT

More details (sorry);

1. Access db is fronted by classic ASP.
2. If possible I don't want to create any new tables.
3. No input is required in order to run the report.
4. There are around 350-400 widgets that could be rented at any one time.
5. Each widget is rented exclusively.
6. Report output example;

   - Month | Year | NumRented
   - Jan  2014  86
   - Feb  2014  113
   - ...

Can a query pick up dates within dates? So literally do a count of the table where date >Dec 31st 2013 AND <1st Feb 2014 (to grab a count for all of January 2014) and would that include the example of the rent starting on the 5th Jan?  So I could just do twelve counts for each year?

Comment: This could get complicated, do you just want a table rented on Jan 5th to count as 1, or would you like it to be a fraction of one? How do you want to present this report? A pivot table? An access report? How do you want to generate this report? Do you want a user to select a month and provide them a count? Do you want to show a whole year in a snap shot and a sum of how many rentals there were per month? We really need a lot more information to help you with this

Comment: Hahaha, just realized I used the word "Table" instead of "widget" a few times, but you get what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

1. create a calendar table, e.g. 
   table = cal_yyyymm  with one column dt_yyyymm as numeric field
2. populate the table with ... say 5 or 10 years of data
   201401    201402   201403  ...   60 or 120 rows, a small table
3. make a sql

   ```
   Select
       dt_yyyymm,
       count(*) as cnt

   From  cal_yyyymm

   Left Join  rent_table
       On  format(startdate,"yyyymm") >= dt_yyyymm
       And dt_yyyymm  >= format(enddate,"yyyymm")
   ```
4. think about the complications in the data -- --

   widget was rented from 5th Jan 2014 to 8th Jan 2014
   and again rented from 11th Jan 2014 to 21st Jan 2014
   does this count at 1 or 2 in the month?

   if it is 1, then the sql gets more complicated because 
   the rent_table first needs to have its dates converted 
   to yyyymm format, and second needs to be de-duped on rentid,
   and third then joined to cal_  On the dates...